# Woocommerce - trying to extract shipping value for an order

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce and installed a print delivery note plugin. What I am trying to do is edit the print file so if someone selects a certain 'additional shipping rate', it will print the relevant printed postage impression - 1st class vs 2nd class

I have in my head an IF statement based on the value of the shipping (FREE vs £1) which I can I do.

BUT, I'm having problems trying to extract the value so I can check it.

Digging deep it looks like I need to use the get_shipping() method in the WC_Order class so I can check the value - http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html - and this is where I fail.... miserably.

Looking at this page - http ://docs.woothemes.com/document/class-reference/#listofclassesinwoocommerce - I can copy and paste the WC_Cart example directly into the .php file that is used to print from and echo the value successfully, but when I change it to what I think is correct to use get_shipping(), I get  "Fatal error: Call to a member function get_shipping() on a non-object in....." instead.

Here's what I put

```
<?php global $woocommerce;
$order_shipping_total = $woocommerce->order->get_shipping();
echo $order_shipping_total ;
?>
```

Now I am guessing, as I have reached the limit of my ability, I need to initialise the WC_Order class but I'm stumped at how to do this.

Any help would be greatly received.

Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You were almost there! You need to initialise the order indeed. `$woocommerce` has no idea which order you are talking about. So you create an object from the order:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id);
```

Now all information from this order (including your shipping value) is accessible via `$order`. The only thing you need to know is the appropriate `$order_id`.
Since you are in the print delivery notes environment, you can access that value via 
`$wcdn->print->order_id`.

this will do what you need:

```
<?php
global $wcdn;
$order = new WC_Order($wcdn->print->order_id);
$order_shipping_total = $order->get_total_shipping();
echo $order_shipping_total;
?>
```

Comment: the method name was changed at some point from `get_shipping()` to `get_total_shipping()`. Relevent docs page: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html

Answer (score 6):

from > WC 3.you can get the total shipping cost of the current order with

```
<?php
$current_shipping_cost = WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping_total();
echo $current_shipping_cost;
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

[2018 Update]

You can use

```
<?php 
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order_shipping_total = $order->get_shipping_total();
echo $order_shipping_total;
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanations with your code in order to help the person who asked the questions